# How to centre a list element in a bootstrap navbar?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

There should be an image in the top left corner, an input box in the top centre, and user profile link in the top right corner.

The class "text-center" does not work. Float left and right do not work. Text align center does not work. There must be some order of operations that I am missing, or some series of containers that would make this easier. Any ideas?

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/crud"><img id="cornerImg" src="/images/beaker.png"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="centerDiv">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li>

      <!-- POST FORM -->
      <form method="post" class="form-inline" id="userCreateForm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input name="userCreate" type="text" class="form-control" id="userCreateBox" placeholder="Ask your question here!">
            <input name="username" type="text" value="<%= user.username %>" hidden="true">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submitButton">Ask</button>
        </div>
      </form>
   </li>
  </ul>
</div>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li id="userProfile"><a href="/profile/<%= user.username %>"><%= user.username %></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In this edit, the title is left and the profile link is right, but the form is still not centred.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following CSS to centre the Navbar:

```
.navbar .navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
    text-align: center;
}
```

The code will make all of the Navbar elements centered.

Comment: I read this method before and tried it. It's actually not working.

Comment: And I'm not performing any operations already that might interfere with this method.

Comment: I also don't have a navbar-collapse